# Visual Studio taskbar menu fix?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, taskbar

By mistake I deleted my taskbar pinned Visual Studio shortcut. I pinned it back but now it won't show the custom taskbar menu I used to have when right-clicking on the icon. This menu automatically showed the recently opened projects and provided shortcuts to run VS in diagnostics or safemode.

Is there any way I can get that menu back without repairing / reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some problems with Windows Icon Cache.

Try to:

- Open Explorer, on the Tool bar, click onOrganize and then Folder and Search Options
- Go to View tab, select the Show hidden files and folders option
- In the folder bar insert: *%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local*
- Rename the IconCache.db file as IconCacheOld.db
- Restart your Pc